# Keras tuner get two instances of the best model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I use Keras Tuner to get appropriate hyperparameters for my machine learning model.
After configuring the best model, I want to train the best model on two separate datasets and evaluate their performance.
But instead of training one model on both datasets, a new instance of the model should be trained on each dataset seperetely.

Does that work like this?

```
import keras_tuner
import numpy as np

build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    return model

model = build_model(keras_tuner.HyperParameters())


tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective="val_accuracy"
)

tuner.search(np.array(), np.array(), epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)

best_model_0 = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
best_model_1 = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
```

The documentation of the function `get_best_models` says:

```
Returns:
    List of trained model instances sorted from the best to the worst.
```

So `best_model_0` and `best_model_1` should refer to the same instance. If that's the case, how to get two instances of the model?

Comment: I just found out that you can get the best hyperparameters with `best_hyperparameters = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]` and create two instances with `model0 = build_model(best_hyperparameters)` and `model1 = build_model(best_hyperparameters)`.